# Wrapping HTML Element by SmartGWT widgets

Tags: html, gwt, widget, smartgwt

I can wrap HTML button or textbox by GWT widgets by

```
Button helpButton = Button.wrap(DOM.getElementById("btnHelp"));
TextBox userName = Button.wrap(DOM.getElementById("txtName"));
```

But can anyone please tell me how can I wrap HTML Button or TextBox by SmartGWT IButton or TextItem etc.